# Nested generics: Method not returning requested part of passed type, but only the guard type

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to create a method `getCheckedOptions` that returns the selected options from a structure we get from graphql, and so I want it as generic as possible, but this method is not returning `TOption[]`,  but `QuestionOptionWithKey[]` and I don't know if I hit a limitation of typescript or made a mistake somewhere.

I created a simplified version of the code in a sandbox with test code, where all the types seem to be correctly infered, except that on the last line shows the incomplete type is returned.

[runnable test code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=15&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOYD2A7eEBqBDANgV2gF4oBvAawhAC4p5gAnASxQHMBuKAN1wJrqdYBfNgChQkKAEUCdRqijFylPg2YsANFAD6W8RBRYAthBUCNUYSLHho0hMDkoAElngALADwAVO7NQA+BVIAbQpqWlVWAF0aHxkHVEsRZmAIegAzLABjW3jHA0Z6CAB1RmA3XwS0UvKAaUp4b0rHQJIRKCgARzzUeFjm1GCokSSUtMyc2ARkNBKytwBhbLcIbzhEXohNOPt8rELoCAAPVJQAE3gpHpQCopqK6-h7+pBGnb8Uf22Bz9J2qCKG1msXWM3Qog63V2qFuJig7yqsNEgisYwy2Vy0JQAHkwFVnpQ-h0wqY1MjUShUujJgBZPA4BwAZQgOAgWWAPw8dIZjGZrPZP1xVVa-x0egMxhoAHJuUyWWyOdcpRCoCSImYVUg8Y4+lBZbz5QLrkLHENkaJkpTxhj4cdFViidpdDYJXCpV47T9lf81fwySMrHorlj7ibesUVihmWhGAAjVneMO-YgACn1fIVnK8ScCAB9bScfgBKDhQAD0ZagADJgx8kwSQBSqRNMR9YfdBdrUC9Gv8EY4oHb9Bda-j5kmnpHo-A4wns13Puo+0nBydh5dO2O6pQlyLIY9+tczQGROk8Ch2QOWBBgAsVlkKGcJx4+z9YavTiO3-s7vNN44eyaa5thzJcOn7eQh3ODdrlDBdJ30adZ1WedhTA+EVygr9jQXBtdxTDp-kBME5nKJYshWGhQU2e5yJWDxqNmbB8AgIZvmuWF2KxL5-nSRgWTOF4qOmTZmIIYIACIwgk4Yi1iJMhkdCsoCyXpgC6a4gmve0PhTYiaPmOitigPiBJeEt-lUtB1KhD4gn02ZaOWCAADpbMRH9XPcnUXL484UxTbzUCLBRAiClAXLCBRiFMnBBMoIt-kYdIoEC64AH4XLFF0jGgABCYgZXpOV+R0qopRC8p6CQAB3KApXSJAkG9DoimAPB6BQDSsRcrUqngckrGUj06EuRr6CgPAZ1YKBymgYxyiQC4qCba1JigABxSQABkVzaYllA6P1WBVM4ECyJgF1JE6AyDLbtvTQ0yoHRRRWdSBXWlR7Sq9FVfUidh-gcYBWWuwGOj6nUaHuhSonNQMbE2naPULTSgn2p1xVy6UUee1AWtVQ7jvB2aylB9V-RRS1mxte7vwOR1wt1ABBeh6CwEAPHu77M00-N7txn5-BPNEWyR7axOgDG1Qpm6Om4FiwcG0XaZ2xj0EdBXeHFyXjyplXJnu9ZisZjjPJocX6aKFUHPQGgsBQEBBqsugARExzDOc6G1YQE3FCgf5wthGgMf3LFdWCUOOkxnLJXqnmjSxKV0OjwnwilTgtAARmT-5U+B8mpXQUraCQYxc9TiH4JoSO1Qz7OtCwHPNDO+ALsYK76r4+hXch-HBGGVPBE0KOOmyj7sfqwWlRT6O68zgAmCvK4Lt0aqYVJS-LvOLEHix0NtuEo61hAa5IE-pWbtPpUzrPG5zgeA46FEkhd9S+7QLSbzvNlHwnPT3boCchRYy9cc4WRdkgVkLkcBIBYCmD+8BggAAYoiZVbu3BcFkgA)

```js
type ResponseValue = {key: string; value: string};
type Question = {key: string, __typename: string, };

type QuestionHash<TQuestion> = {[key: string]: TQuestion};

interface QuestionnaireWithQuestionsWithKeys<TQuestion> {
  questions: TQuestion[]
};

interface ResponseWithCache<TResponse, TQuestionnaire extends QuestionnaireWithQuestionsWithKeys<TQuestion>, TQuestion> {
  response: TResponse;
  questionnaire: TQuestionnaire;
}

interface QuestionOptionWithKey {
  key: string;
}

interface MultiSelectQuestion<MultiSelectQuestionOption> {
  __typename: 'MultiSelectQuestion';
  key: string;
  options: MultiSelectQuestionOption[];
};

interface TextQuestion {
  __typename: 'TextQuestion';
  key: string;
}

type QuestionWithOptionsWhenSensible<TOption> = (MultiSelectQuestion<TOption> | TextQuestion);

interface QuestionnaireWithQuestionOptionKeys<
  TQuestion extends QuestionWithOptionsWhenSensible<TOption>,
  TOption extends QuestionOptionWithKey,
> {
  questions: TQuestion[];
}

function getCheckedOptions<
  TQuestionnaire extends QuestionnaireWithQuestionOptionKeys<TQuestion, TOption>,
  TQuestion extends QuestionWithOptionsWhenSensible<TOption>,
  TOption extends QuestionOptionWithKey,
>(  
  responseWithCache: ResponseWithCache<ResponseValue[], TQuestionnaire, TQuestion>,
  fieldKey: ResponseValue["key"]
): TOption[] {
  // const question = getQuestion(responseWithCache, fieldKey);
  const question = responseWithCache.questionnaire.questions.find((question) => question.key == fieldKey)
  if (question?.__typename != 'MultiSelectQuestion') throw 'foo';
  return question.options;
}
```

---

Edit: Created [a simpler version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHtx1NAPAFQElIBbAPmQG8AoZZYUgLmSNIG5qBfD60SWRCmIQSBAMoBXAEYMRFGnQDO02SWb5JM9l2q9w0eEmQB1BgAsA0hACeVWsgDWN5orBRQAcw6ddMCSAQwYExkDwgwYVF7VhFkCAAPSBAAE0VkSNw4EGsyajIACjgoD2YMLBwoAkiyAEp1SLs6KHCJKBBkIo8AOlVvX39A4PawsE1VXGiGhKTU9NJxFVIyABposdI4xIgUtNMwSxs8wuLSzDBsEDwY8jqWddiFZARMV3oNgF5Q8Mjjjxr7ZpgVrtVRdZRaER9ajPECvZJwc50T6PVTMR5KRYiNH2Oh0JzWZgAIgchNWuNxADc4AAbCQQIkwdDoQk45A+Og+bi6GGKdDUiBdanoDz5EY-eHnGoAfjBmJIXSptIgNQ4PL5AqFIpG9xI+QlcGlCppdJV1CAA).

Is there a way to make typescript infer the right type on the last line? Seems to me like there should, why else allow TSubitem as a  return type?

```
interface Container<TItem> {
  item: TItem;
};

interface Item<TSubitem> {
  subitem: TSubitem;
}

interface WithKey {
  key: string;
}

function getItem<
  TItem extends Item<any>
>(arg: Container<TItem>): TItem {
  return arg.item;
}

function getSubitem<
  TItem extends Item<TSubitem>,
  TSubitem extends WithKey
>(arg: Container<TItem>): TSubitem {
  const item = getItem(arg)
  return item.subitem;
}

const data  = {
  item: {
    subitem: {
      key: "k",
      value: "foo"
    }
  }
};

console.log(getItem(data)?.subitem.value);
console.log(getSubitem(data)?.value);
```

Comment: i think you might need to extend QuestionOptionWithKey  since it will work if you give that interface the description: string. Else you will have to explain what is a question option and have QuestionOptionWithKey  extend that. Code is technically working but there is not actual description of TOption since that is generic.

Comment: The whole idea behind generics is that I should't need to add description to QuestionOptionWithKey, since the method doesn't care that is there and it might not when  called in a different view. 

In [this simpler case](https://shorturl.at/fpqwT) it works fine, with getQuestion not knowing there is a title, but the TQuestion being correctly returned as the GQL types with a title.

If I misunderstand  your comment, can you  clarify what I  need  to  change?

Comment: The description is there and it does out put, but you are trying to reference it with the code hence typescript do not know about it. So even if the ide does not recognize it the value is there.

Comment: Sure, but I use typescript because of the type-safety and I'd have to cast to any to make the compiler happy, losing all of the benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has less to do with the nested generics and more with the similarly scoped generics. You cannot infer generics from one another, and generics are only inferred if they are directly tied to the arguments of the function (OR the return type if explicitly assigned).

```
function getSubitem<
  TItem extends Item<TSubitem>, //<--TItem is inferred from args,
  TSubitem extends WithKey //<--TSubItem isn't inferred at all
>(args: Container<TItem>): TSubItem //=> WithKey
{...}
```

Instead you can do this

```js
function getSubitem<
  TItem extends Item<WithKey>
>(args: Container<TItem>){...}

// Or if you really need the old generic shape
function getSubitem2<
  TItem extends Item<TSubitem>, //not used, except for generic override
  TSubitem extends WithKey
>(arg: Container<Item<TSubitem>>): TSubitem {
  const item = getItem(arg)
  return item.subitem;
}
```

[View on TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXKQQW)

In your more complex example, you try to infer `TOption` from your other generics in a sort of roundabout way. Instead use less generics, and make it a sort of single source of truth.

```
function getCheckedOptions<
  TOption extends QuestionOptionWithKey,
>(
  responseWithCache: ResponseWithCache<
    ResponseValue[], 
    QuestionnaireWithQuestionOptionKeys<QuestionWithOptionsWhenSensible<TOption>, TOption>, 
    QuestionWithOptionsWhenSensible<TOption>
  >,
  fieldKey: ResponseValue["key"]
): TOption[] {
  // const question = getQuestion(responseWithCache, fieldKey);
  const question = responseWithCache.questionnaire.questions.find((question) => question.key == fieldKey)
  if (question?.__typename != 'MultiSelectQuestion') throw 'foo';
  return question.options;
}
```

[View on TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mLlq2m)

More or less, using less generics is better, and the generic should be the deepest type of all the generics to make inference work best.

Comment: Awesome, thank you  so much,  exactly what I need! Points will be coming your way as soon  as SO allows it. Will try to edit the question a bit this weekend to put the focus on the simpler case to make it more generally useful. If  you have better  title, let me know.